# How can I effect the same horizontal alignment, here?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, exam

When I start with the code shown below, I experience the following alignment problem:

[image]

How do I make it correct alignment?

Also, I want to encircle some special question numbers... How can I do that?

```
\documentclass[]{exam}

\begin{document}


        \begin{center}
        \fbox{SECTION-A}
       \end{center}

\begin{itemize}
\item Answer all the 15 questions.  
\item  Each question contains four options. Choose the most suitable answer from the four alternatives.         
\item Each question carries 1 mark   \hfill{$15\times 1=15$}
\end{itemize}

\begin{questions}
 \question 
     \begin{center}
         \fbox{SECTION-B}
        \end{center}
 \begin{itemize}
 \item Answer 10 questions. 
 \item  Answer any 9 questions from the first 14 questions. Question no. 30 is compulsory.      
 \item Each question carries 2 marks.   \hfill{$10\times 2=20$}
 \end{itemize}
 \end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I want the alignment as in the section-B.. of my figure..

Comment: why not use a section command rather than the horrible markup `\begin{center}\fbox{SECTION-A}\end{center}` which means latex does not know it is a section so you can not reference it, page break could happen immediately after it etc, also `{}` are not needed in `{$10\times 2=20$}` as `$ $` already forms a group.

Comment: do you want the 1. in front of the boxed section B ?

Comment: @David You seem to be asking two unrelated questions, here. On TeX.SX, we try to keep unrelated questions on separate pages. If you have multiple questions that are unrelated to one another, you should ask each in a separate TeX.SX "question". You'll stand a better chance of getting a satisfactory answer to each of your questions.

Comment: I don't want.. the 1. in front of the boxed section B. its just a question number  in section A.@DavidCarlisle

Comment: But that is my question. the alignment is different because the whole of section B is inside a `\question` which puts 1. in from of the fake "section b heading" and indents the rest of the text. If you don't want that just don't nest it.

Answer (score 2):

You can

1. use `\section`/`\section*`
2. use `\uplevel`

I have used `titlesec` to center and frame the title. But putting the numbers for  sections is a bad idea. But since I don't understand your needs properly, I left them as such. I have also used `enumitem` to squeeze the spacing of items.

Here is a sample code:

```
\documentclass[]{exam}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\myframed}[1]{\fbox{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{}{0em}{\myframed}

\begin{document}
\section*{Section-A}
\begin{itemize}[nosep]
\item Answer all the 15 questions.
\item  Each question contains four options. Choose the most suitable answer from the four alternatives.
\item Each question carries 1 mark   \hfill{$15\times 1=15$}
\end{itemize}
\begin{questions}
  \question One of these things is not like the others; one of these
       things is not the same. Which one is different?
          \begin{oneparchoices}
            \choice John
            \choice Paul
            \choice George
            \choice Ringo
            \CorrectChoice Socrates
          \end{oneparchoices}
  \question One of these things is not like the others; one of these
       things is not the same. Which one is different?
          \begin{oneparchoices}
            \choice John
            \choice Paul
            \choice George
            \choice Ringo
            \CorrectChoice Socrates
          \end{oneparchoices}
  \question One of these things is not like the others; one of these
       things is not the same. Which one is different?
          \begin{oneparchoices}
            \choice John
            \choice Paul
            \choice George
            \choice Ringo
            \CorrectChoice Socrates
          \end{oneparchoices}

\uplevel{%
\section*{Section-B}
 \begin{itemize}[nosep]
 \item Answer 10 questions.
 \item  Answer any 9 questions from the first 14 questions. Question no. 30 is compulsory.
 \item Each question carries 2 marks.   \hfill{$10\times 2=20$}
 \end{itemize}
}
  \question What is the other question?
  \question What is the other question?
  \question What is the other question?
 \end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]